# Cannot change image size, it doesn't appear in the source code

Tags: templates, beamerposter

I downloaded a poster template from this [link](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/dreuw-deselaers-poster) (got the `.zip`). While working with TeXmaker, I would like to change the logo image. As far as I see, the original logo is accessed by:

```
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Location of the graphics files
```

I couldn't find the command that includes the logo on the PDF. However, I replaced the logo I wanted on the indicated folder, getting an image size which I cannot change.

How can I change the image from the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in file `beamerthemeI6pd2.sty` you can find the definition for `\setbeamertemplate{headline}`. Inside this you can find the command `\includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{logo.png}` you need to change, for example to `\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image.png}`. I used there the image `example-image.png` picture from package `MWE` you need to have installed but you have not to load it ...

With the following MWE

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Dreuw & Deselaer's Poster
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (11/04/13)
%
% Created by:
% Philippe Dreuw and Thomas Deselaers
% http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster with a portrait orientation and an a0 paper size

\usetheme{I6pd2} % Use the I6pd2 theme supplied with this template

\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym} % For including math equations, theorems, symbols, etc

%\usepackage{times}\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  % Uncomment to use Times as the main font
%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} % Uncomment to use a Serif font within math environments

\boldmath % Use bold for everything within the math environment

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables

\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Location of the graphics files

\usecaptiontemplate{\small\structure{\insertcaptionname~\insertcaptionnumber: }\insertcaption} % A fix for figure numbering


\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
  \leavevmode

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
    \begin{columns}[T]
      \begin{column}{.02\paperwidth}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.7\paperwidth}
        \vskip4ex
        \raggedleft
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\LARGE{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}     
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.25\paperwidth}
        \vskip8ex
        \begin{center}
%         \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{logo.png}
          \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image.png} % <=============================
        \end{center}
        \vskip2ex
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.02\paperwidth}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \vskip2ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \rule{0pt}{3pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\huge Unnecessarily Complicated Research Title} % Poster title

\author{John Smith, James Smith and Jane Smith} % Author(s)

\institute{Department and University Name} % Institution(s)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FOOTER TEXT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\leftfoot}{http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com} % Left footer text

\newcommand{\rightfoot}{john@smith.com} % Right footer text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks

\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame

\begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of two major columns, each of which can be subdivided further with another \begin{columns} block - the [t] argument aligns each column's content to the top

\begin{column}{.02\textwidth}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{.465\textwidth} % The first column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Objectives}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Donec fringilla, velit id lobortis commodo, eros dui consectetur mi, ut interdum lorem dui sed mauris.
\item Nulla ac nulla rhoncus est bibendum ullamcorper:
\item Quisque vestibulum, nisl sit amet gravida ultricies dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus musobortis commodo, eros dui consectetur mi.
\end{enumerate}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
\item Donec fringilla, velit id lobortis commodo, eros dui consectetur mi, ut interdum lorem dui sed mauris. Duis id sem nunc, a pharetra odio. Phasellus posuere \alert{semper massa}, id bibendum ligula tristique at. Integer sit amet vulputate turpis. Sed erat lacus, faucibus at viverra et, mattis nec sem. Cras faucibus \alert{scelerisque} cursus. Opet volutpat ligula. Duis semper lorem eget dui dignissim porttitor. Nulla facilisi. In ullamcorper lorem quis dolor iaculis nec egestas enim ultricies. Cras ut mauris elit, ut lacinia dui. Proin in ante et libero hendrerit iaculis. Nulla eu erat a urna laoreet auctor id a turpis. Nam mollis tristique neque eu luctus. Suspendisse rutrum congue nisi sed convallis. Aenean id neque dolor.
\end{itemize}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MATERIALS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Materials}

\begin{columns} % Subdivide the first main column
\begin{column}{.54\textwidth} % The first subdivided column within the first main column
\begin{itemize}
\item Vestibulum nisl, quis euismod velit eros in ligula.
\begin{itemize}
\item Cras rhoncus quam et augue convallis in elementum urna tincidunt.
\end{itemize}
\item Proin ut vestibulum augue.
\begin{itemize}
\item Donec dapibus sagittis neque eu ultrices.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{.43\textwidth} % The second subdivided column within the first main column
\centering
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{placeholder.jpg}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns} % End of the subdivision

\begin{itemize}
\item Curabitur sapien ligula, faucibus in feugiat quis, vestibulum a turpis.
\begin{itemize}
\item Phasellus quis nunc neque. Suspendisse mauris diam, suscipit non gravida in, placerat id enim. Ut nec ipsum in lectus ultrices sagittis.
\item Ut nec ipsum in lectus ultrices sagittis.
\item Phasellus quis nunc neque.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   METHODS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Methods}

\begin{itemize}
\item Maecenas Vel Nisl Elit
\begin{itemize}
\item Suspendisse potenti. Fusce a est eget turpis rhoncus varius sed sed dui. Cras justo nibh, bibendum a cursus eget, consequat et dui. Maecenas vel nisl elit, sed dignissim dolor. 
\item In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
\end{itemize}

\item Viewpoint Matching Constraints
\begin{itemize}
\item Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
\item Proin in nisi diam.
\item Nam ultricies pellentesque nunc, ultrices volutpat nisl ultrices a.
\end{itemize}

\item Volutpat 
\begin{itemize}
\item Duis semper lorem eget dui dignissim porttitor.
\item Nulla facilisi. In ullamcorper lorem quis dolor.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MATHEMATICAL SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Mathematical Section}

\begin{itemize}
\item Maecenas Ultricies Feugiat Velit Non Mattis.
\begin{itemize}
\item Duis ante erat, bibendum nec tempus nec, interdum quis est. Nulla at mollis tortor. Phasellus quis leo dolor, aliquam laoreet orci $X$ Donec dapibus sagittis neque eu nec, interdum quis est. $Y_n, n=1,\cdots,N$ ndum nec tempus nec, interd
\begin{align*}
X \rightarrow r(X) & = \arg \max_{c} \Big\{ \max_n \big\{ \sum_{x_i \in X} \delta(x_i,Y_{n,c})\big\} \Big\} 
\end{align*}
\item Cras faucibus scelerisque cursus. Proin ut vestibulum augue. $\delta(x_i,Y_{n,c})$
\end{itemize}
\item Fusce tempus arcu id ligula varius dictum. Donec ut nisl dui, ac consectetur elit. In nec enim porta augue venenatis sollicitudin. Phasellus quis nunc neque. Suspendisse mauris diam, suscipit non gravida in, placerat id enim. Ut nec ipsum in lectus ultrices sagittis.
\end{itemize}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of the first column

\begin{column}{.03\textwidth}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{.465\textwidth} % The second column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Results: Table}

\begin{itemize}
\item Ased Aliquet Luctus Lectus
\end{itemize}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}

\begin{itemize}
\item Sollicitudin Vel Orci
\item Maecenas Ultricies Feugiat Velit Non Mattis.
\end{itemize}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}

\end{block}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Results: Figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{placeholder.jpg}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONCLUSION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Conclusion}

\begin{itemize}
\item Opet volutpat ligula. Duis semper lorem eget dui dignissim porttitor. Nulla facilisi. In ullamcorper lorem quis dolor iaculis nec egestas enim ultricies. Cras ut mauris elit, ut lacinia dui. Proin in ante et libero hendrerit iaculis.
\item Nulla eu erat a urna laoreet auctor id a turpis. Nam mollis tristique neque eu luctus. Suspendisse rutrum congue nisi sed convallis. 
\item Aenean id neque dolor.
\item Opet volutpat ligula. Duis semper lorem eget dui dignissim porttitor. Nulla facilisi. In ullamcorper lorem quis dolor iaculis nec egestas enim ultricies. Cras ut mauris elit, ut lacinia dui. Proin in ante et libero hendrerit iaculis.
\end{itemize}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{References}

\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster
\small{\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample}}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Acknowledgments}

\begin{itemize}
\item Nam mollis tristique neque eu luctus. Suspendisse rutrum congue nisi sed convallis. Aenean id neque dolor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
\end{itemize}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=orange!70} % Change the block title color

\begin{block}{Contact Information}

\begin{itemize}
\item Web: \href{http://www.university.edu/smithlab}{http://www.university.edu/smithlab}
\item Email: \href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}
\item Phone: +1 (000) 111 1111
\end{itemize}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of the second column

\begin{column}{.015\textwidth}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame

\end{document}
```

you get the changed result you want:

[image]

Change the name for the image and the width for your needs ...

Answer (score 0):

### Interpreting the template - which commands do what?

1. `\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Location of the graphics files` is not the command which accesses the logo. Rather, it is the command which specifies which folder to **look in** to find the image that you want to include.
2. There is no command in the template which accesses the logo explicitly. As far as I can tell, this is a part of the `beamerposter` package, so you have to edit the logo size externally.

---

### In general - how to include image / change image size?

```
\includegraphics[scale = 1.2]{figures/logoname.extension}
```

or

```
\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{figures/logoname.extension}
```

Important note: These commands will not work if you include the line

```
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
```

The commands I've used are more general; they allow you to specify exactly which source folder you want to look at. To make it clear why I've done this, imagine that you have the following folder structure:

1. Parent folder (this is where you keep your .tex file)

   - Child folder 1 (called `figures` - this is where you keep general images)
   - Child folder 2 (called `logos` - this is where you keep general logos)

If you set the graphics path to `figures`, you won't be able to access files in the `logos` folder, unless you shift the `logos` folder into the `figures` folder. Rather than deal with that, my suggestion (which includes the path of the folder when using `\includegraphics`) allows you to specify it then.

Apologies if I've misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Thevesh! However, the main issue was solved dealing with the beamerthemeI6pd2.sty file, where the \includegrafics was executed.

Comment: @Ignacio No worries. Do consider upvoting my answer (and certainly the accepted answer). :)

Comment: Sure! Sorry for the loong delay! I think I don't have enough reputation tu publicly show the upvote, but it should be recorded anyway